# Web Service in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

Is there any way I can **call a web service** in the Pine Script? I have not seen any example doing it but was curious if it was possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not possible for now. The only external connection available in Pine is to TV-provided data feeds through `security()`, `financial()` and `quandl()` functions.